# UIImagePickerController Gallery delegate is not calling

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController with this code

```
    func openCamera()
{
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
    {

        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
        presentViewController(picker,
                              animated: true, 
                              completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {
        openGallary()
    }
}
func openGallary()
{    
    let menuViewController =  UIImagePickerController()

    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320 )
    //menuViewController.tableView = FrontTable

    let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = flagBtn
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: 15, 
        y: 25, 
        width: 1,
        height: 1)
    presentViewController(
        menuViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
     picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  let image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    flagBtn.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    flagBtn.setImage(image, forState: .Highlighted)
    flagBtn.setImage(image, forState: .Selected)
}
```

With camera delegate is working fine but with gallery delegate is not working. For camera I have define the "picker" variable in the class and define it's delegate self in "Viewdidload". I have also tried to use picker variable in openGallary function but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these 2 lines might help:

```
menuViewController.delegate = self
menuViewController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
```

Make sure you have added `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to your `ViewController`.